# Xcode distribute app via Ad Hoc with correct cert/profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I need to ensure I am distributing my Ad Hoc correctly to avoid issues...

I’m using Xcode 12.5 which is configured with my Apple Developer account that I activated last week. When I log into the Apple Developer portal, and look under Profiles, I don’t see any profiles. Under Certificates, I see one for Development and Distribution.

When I go into my Xcode Archives and select a build to distribute as Ad Hoc, and select “Automatically manage signing”, does that mean:

1. The Ad Hoc app will be signed with the “Distribution" Cert that will expire in roughly a year?
2. Will the app continue to work until the expiration of the Distribution cert (nearly a year from now)?
3. Are there no Profiles on the Apple developer account since I selected "Automatically manage signing"?

Comment: An ad-hoc build is valid only for the device UDIDs included in its embedded provisioning profile (typically the devices that were registered in your account at the time you built the app) and the app will run for about 6 months from memory. Unless your app needs specific entitlements Xcode will use a wildcard provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have the UDID registered in App Dev Account. I assume it will use the Distribution Cert? I don't see a wildcard provisioning profile so I imagine xCode creates one during distribution? Lastly, why 6 months and not till cert expires.. Feel free to answer question so I can flag as correct..

Comment: Because ad hoc is only intended for testing. It seems that the validity of the app is based on your membership year start date, so if your membership expires on June 10, an ad hoc build built today would work until June 10 https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115245